# JEST in package.json

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, bucklescript

I have a question about MatchTest in package.json
I have a file call EventSourceMock.bs.js which is a library to mock event source.
Plus I have other files like CalculatorTest.bs.js
Then my package MatchTest is set to this `"**/**(Spec|Test).bs.js"`
When I run the test, CalculatorTest.bs.js passed but the result said this
```
FAIL  EventSourceMock.bs.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
Your test suite must contain at least one test.

  at node_modules/jest-cli/build/test_scheduler.js:157:22
```

```

It looks like jest thought that EventSourceMock.bs.js is a test file instead of a library.

So I was playing around and I changed MatchTest to `"**/**{(Spec|Test)}.bs.js"`

Surprisingly it passed..

Any idea?